# Flutter Expanded and Flexible not working when I execute the app in release

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, display

Flutter Expanded and Flexible not working when I execute the app in release. In debug it works just fine, but when i install it on a physical device in release it does not show the listed elements I'm trying to display.

I've double checked the elements are present but they are not displayed. When I try to display them instead of a Expanded or Flexible in a Container with a fixed height everything working fine even in release. I just need the list to be displayed and automatically adjust to screen size.

```
Flexible(
child: Container(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5)
 height comented ->        // height: 370, 
width: double.infinity,
child: ListView.builder(
itemCount: state.selectedLinesToDisplay.length,
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
LineModel line = state.selectedLinesToDisplay![index];
return SlideInLeft(child: LineDisplay(data: line));
                  
                      },
                    ),
                                  ),
                  ),


// THE LINE DISPLAY
Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(12),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(12)),
                color: AppColors.primaryColor),
            child: ListTile(
                leading: 

                    FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.bus, size: 30,),
                
                title: Text(
                  'Линија број: ' + data!.r_linija_broj,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                subtitle: AutoSizeText(
                  data!.r_linija_naziv,
                  style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.white),
                  maxLines: 1,
                ),
                trailing: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {})));
      },'''
```

Comment: please provide any code

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code rather than putting it as an answer in a different post. You should also consider adding the property: `shrinkWrap: true` in your listview